# Rails Upload with Carrierwave, Fog to S3 - HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I've been following the excellent Rails Cast by Ryan Bates on uploading files to S3 (Episode 383). Things work fine - but...

I'd like to use the images' HTTP URL instead of HTTPS.

Tried looking in the Carrierwave documentation, but could not find if this was an option.
Tried to see if this was an S3 setting, but by default it seems to support HTTP and HTTPS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried looking for this too @Luke, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kamilski81 - not yet. It's not crazy critical bu hope someone could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `asset_host` config parameter:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.fog_directory  = 'yourbucket'

  # Forcing use of HTTP
  config.asset_host = "http://#{config.fog_directory}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  ...
end
```

If your bucket is in a region other than US Standard you might need to add that part to the host as well.

Answer (score 3):

CarrierWave 0.9.0 [added a configuration param `fog_use_ssl_for_aws`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/4f46d2a9751821afba43c9c0eb603e795fa53580) to disable SSL for public_url.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.fog_use_ssl_for_aws = false
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you want to allow users to download files from your S3 bucket, you will need to create permissions for everyone to list and download files.

That can be done in your S3 bucket configuration panel, under the "Permissions" tab. By default, S3 file will be private so you would need an authenticated url to access them.